# How to capture and store email of user with Stripe-Elixir

Tags: elixir, stripe-payments, phoenix-framework, stripe-elixir

I have the following code and I am able to create new users. The email is not stored.

Code:

```
    defmodule StripeTestWeb.PaymentController do
      use StripeTestWeb, :controller
      use Stripe.API

      def index(conn, _params) do

        {:ok, customer_data} = Stripe.Customer.create(%{email: conn.body_params['stripeEmail']})

        render(conn, "index.html")
      end
    end
```

[image]

How do I capture and store their email ?

Comment: You should use double quotes instead of single quotes when fetching from the params. `conn.body_params['stripeEmail'] != conn.body_params["stripeEmail"]`. Also why are you using `conn.body_params` instead of pattern matching on the `params` argument?

Comment: Singles quotes make a charlist instead of a binary

Comment: @AbM I jumped into Elixir after writing JS and I am use to objects. Bad habit

Answer (score 0):

There are two glitches with this code I can spot on:

1. there is a significant difference between single quotes and double quotes in Elixir’s literals/terms. The difference is described in details in [Elixir Guide, Chapter 6](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html) and in general is: single quotes used for *char lists* that have basically nothing in common with *binaries* (strings.)

Look:

```rb
iex|1 ▶ 'abc' == [97, 98, 99]
#⇒ true
```

`'abc'` is essentially the same as (in pseudocode)

```rb
[
   ascii-value-of(character a),
   ascii-value-of(character b),
   ascii-value-of(character c)
]
```

This should be probably considered a legacy that came back from XX century. Whenever you need a binary (the string,) *always use double quotes*.

2. Another issue would be you assign and immediately discard the value returned from `Stripe.Customer.create`. This is unlikely what you actually want to do; to pass it to the underlying controller, use [`Plug.Conn.assign/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#assign/3) (or at least validate the outcome of a call to `create` function and somehow deal with errors.

---

The summing up, the solution that would be likely robust looks like:

```rb
defmodule StripeTestWeb.PaymentController do
  use StripeTestWeb, :controller
  use Stripe.API

  def index(conn, %{"stripeEmail" => email} = _params) do
    with {:ok, customer_data} <- Stripe.Customer.create(%{email: email}) do
      conn
      |> assign(:customer_data, customer_data)
      |> render("index.html")
    else
      # render error page
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: When I use the with statement I get an error. I am not familiar enough to know what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: For that we have a documentation [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1). Unfortunately I cannot be of any help unless you have at least _what error do you get_ shared.